# Limit of the quotient of two holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I want to calculate the limit as $\displaystyle \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(z)-1}{\sin(2z)}$. I know that for real variables, this value is $0$, using L'Hopital.

Is there some way to justify that this value must be 0 in the complex case? That is, when we go to $0$ along any line?

I am also struggling with $\dfrac{\cos(z)\sin(z)-z}{(\sin(z))^2}$, as z goes to zero. With L'hopital this is ok after some work in the real case (I got the answer $0$), but what about the complex case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with L'Hopital for complex-valued functions in general. But for holomorphic functions (for limits at a finite point) it's never really needed: you can fall back on the definition of derivative, or more generally on Taylor series expansion.

In the first example, consider that

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(z)-1}{\sin(2z)} 
=\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(z)-1}{z} \bigg/ \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(2z)}{z}  
$$
where both limits on the right exist and can be evaluated by the definition of derivative.

For the second example,

$$\lim_{z\to0}\dfrac{\cos(z)\sin(z)-z}{(\sin(z))^2} 
= \lim_{z\to0}\dfrac{\cos(z)\sin(z)-z}{z^2} \bigg/ \lim_{z\to0}\dfrac{(\sin(z))^2}{z^2} 
$$
where, again, both limits on the right exist. The second one can be related to the derivative of sine at $0$, while in the first one you probably want to expand the numerator into Taylor series up to second order.

Comment: Thanks, I see that they remind us very much about l-hopital. The second trick was very good! Is that usual. If we have to use l'hopital once in the real case we in the comple case divide by z, two time we dived by z*z, three times we divide by z*z*z?

Comment: Yes, if the denominator has zero of order $m$ (as in the other answer), you would divide both numerator and denominator by $z^m$ to get a finite nonzero limit in the denominator; then the quotient rule of limits is applied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the fact that
$$
\sin (2z)=zf(z)\quad \text{and}\quad \cos z-1=z^2g(z),
$$
where $f,g$ entire analytic function, with $f(0)=1$ and $g(z)=-\frac{1}{2}$.

This is due to the fact the $z=0$ is zero of both functions, simple for $\sin (2z)$ and double root for $\cos z-1$.

Note that $z=0$ is a zero of order $m$ for $f$ if
$$
f(0)=f'(0)=\cdots=f^{(m-1)}(0)=0 \quad\text{and}\quad f^{(m)}(0)\ne 0.
$$